# Use `robots.txt` in a multilingual site

Tags: seo, sitemap, robots.txt

Having to manage a multilingual site, where users are redirected to a local version of site, like

```
myBurger.com/en // for users from US, UK, etc..
myBurger.com/fr // for users from France, Swiss, etc...
```

How should be organized the `robots.txt` file in pair with the sitemap?

```
myBurger.com/robots.txt // with - Sitemap: http://myBurger.com/??/sitemap
OR
myBurger.com/en/robots.txt  // with - Sitemap: http://myBurger.com/en/sitemap
myBurger.com/fr/robots.txt  // with - Sitemap: http://myBurger.com/fr/sitemap
```

kwnowing that `en` and `fr` sites are in fact independent entities not sharing common content, even if similar appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put one robots.txt at the top level.

> The robots.txt file must be in the top-level directory of the host,
>   accessible though the appropriate protocol and port number.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: I have an umbraco multilingual site... so for a hostname I have 2 sites: host/en and host/fr... the users are redirected to one of the site by geolocalization

Comment: what difference does that make ? still need to put robots.txt at top level.

Comment: the difference makes the therm "top level"... in my case I have 2 top levels for one hostname...

Comment: No - you have one top level. You have two directories. robots.txt needs to be in the top level of the domain.

Comment: I use the Umbraco CMS. I have a situation like in the first image of this page: https://goo.gl/WROPbC

Comment: Never mind what you see in the inners of your cms, it is the top level of your domain, like example.com/robots.txt . and that is it.  I have linked to the relevant docs above, there is nothing more to say here.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `robots.txt` at the root: `myBurger.com/robots.txt` and register your sitemaps in the `robots.txt` file using the `sitemap:` directive (see an example I [maintain](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/robots-txt-implementation-seo.html) if necessary).

Comment: The link is dead, Jérôme. In any case, from how I understood it, it is recommended to write self contained answers, see "Provide context for links". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer (I am never sure if I should bug people about stuff like this in old answers.)